# Неправильное число в названии следующей привилегии. А ещё там лишнее сокращение

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, привилегии, множественное-число

На странице https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges сбоку есть плашка, в которой показывается следующая привилегия.

У меня плашка выглядит так:

[image: скриншот текущего перевода]

Мне кажется, что должно должно быть множественное число: не "создавать синоним метки", а "создавать синонимы меток".

Аргументация:

- В другом разделе справки (то есть собственно [в описании этой привилегии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) множественное число).
- Множественное число звучит лучше. Ведь участник может создавать много синонимов, а не только 1.

---

Кроме этого, зачем нужно сокращение? На странице вроде ещё много места. Думаю, что это тоже стоит исправить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перевод привилегии поправил (вроде бы тот):

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14745

Сокращение развернул (раньше оно было актуально из-за узкого блока в профиле)

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/6761

Надо посмотреть, что ничего не поедет после обновления. Текущая сборка 2023.9.25.43644

Comment: Применилось. И ничего не поехало: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkgav.png

Comment: @Зонтик надо смотреть всё же в контексте, и стоит учитывать наличие Responsive UI, т.е. проверить всевозможные размеры окошек. Обычно для этого хватает подвигать окно браузера и посмотреть что происходит с контентом.

Comment: С изменениями окна всё нормально (проверял в хроме). Я потом ещё попробую зайти через другой браузер (Fierfox и может быть даже internet Explorer)

Comment: @Зонтик похоже, что и ["След. знак"](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/225) можно написать без сокращения. Попробую применить перевод.